# Google Action SDK with Dialogflow - Configuration and release issue

Tags: configuration, release, dialogflow-es

### Summary :

I have 1 project in Google configured with the Google Action to be "Action SDK" instead of "Dialogflow". (in order to reach my api instead of dialogflow with Google Assistant)

=> When I release my project in Alpha, the Google Action Configuration (fulfilment tool) of the project is reset to "Dialogflow" and ignore my config.

### Details :

I've a Chatbot project with the following flow :

1. Google Assistant sending request to a spring boot app (running as app engine on GCP).
2. The spring boot app calls dialogflow using grpc to identify the intent and reply to Google Assistant.

I have 2 projects in GAction :

- one for dialogflow definition
- one for the configuration Action SDK (to reach my app on GCP). This one has the right to reach the dialogflow project (IAM config)

Why 2 projects ? Because when I use 1 project containing Dialogflow intents AND Action SDK configuration, each time I save an intent in Dialogflow, **it reset the configuration of the action** and set it as Dialogflow Action => ignore the Action SDK.

So, the 2 different projects are my workaround for this issue.

**The issue I'm facing now is :**

When I release a version of the project containing the configuration on ACTION SDK, when I try to test it, the configuration is reset to ACTION DIALOGFLOW **(and so not reaching my api anymore)**.

How can I make a release that keep configuration set (beeing 'Action SDK') at the moment I push the "release" button ??

Anyone else facing issues with action sdk configuration ?